# show validation after click outside the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, phone-number

I use Mui, Yup, React Hook Form and react-phone-number-input package in my form ... I want show validation and error message after click outside the input.

this is my method and mode to always stay on onChange until the length reaches 10 to activate the button:

```js
const PhoneNumberSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    phoneNumber: Yup.string().test('validateUsername', 'Invalid Phone Number', function (value: any) {
      const isValidPhone = isValidPhoneNumber(value || '');
      if (!isValidPhone || value?.length < 10) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }),
  });

  const methods = useForm<UserPhoneNumberType>({
    resolver: yupResolver(PhoneNumberSchema),
    defaultValues,
    mode: 'onChange',
  });

const {
control,
handleSubmit,
getValues,
formState: { isValid, errors },
  } = methods;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and this is my form:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<Dialog fullWidth={true} open={true} keepMounted sx={{ minWidth: 600 }} onClose={handleBackRoute}>
        <FormProvider methods={methods} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ py: 3 }}>
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} alignItems="center" sx={{ justifyContent: 'space-between', px: 2 }}>
              <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" alignItems="center">
                <IconButton sx={{ p: 0, mr: 2 }} onClick={handleBackRoute}>
                  <ArrowLeft />
                </IconButton>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="text.primary">
                  {userPhoneNumber?.id ? 'Edit Phone Number' : 'Phone Number'}
                </Typography>
              </Stack>
              {!userPhoneNumber?.id ? (
                <IconButton onClick={handleBackRoute}>
                  <CloseSquare variant="Outline" />
                </IconButton>
              ) : (
                <IconButton onClick={closeHandler}>
                  <CloseSquare variant="Outline" />
                </IconButton>
              )}
            </Stack>
            <Divider />
            <ParentPhoneInputStyle>
              <Stack sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
                  Phone Number
                </Typography>
                {!userPhoneNumber?.id ? (
                  <Controller
                    name="phoneNumber"
                    control={control}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <PhoneNumber
                        value={field.value}
                        isError={!!errors?.phoneNumber}
                        placeHolder="Enter phone number"
                        onChange={field.onChange}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" sx={{ mt: 1, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
                    <Typography variant="body2">{userPhoneNumber.phoneNumber}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="primary">
                      {userPhoneNumber.status}
                    </Typography>
                  </Stack>
                )}
              </Stack>
              {!!errors?.phoneNumber && (
                <Typography component="div" variant="caption" sx={{ color: 'error.main', mt: 0.5 }}>
                  {errors?.phoneNumber?.message}
                </Typography>
              )}
            </ParentPhoneInputStyle>
            <Divider sx={{ mt: !!errors?.phoneNumber ? '32px !important' : '16px !important' }} />
            {!userPhoneNumber?.id ? (
              <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} alignItems="center" sx={{ justifyContent: 'space-between', px: 2 }}>
                <Link href={'/profile/select-audience-phone-number'} passHref>
                  <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    startIcon={<Eye size="18" color={theme.palette.text.primary} />}
                    onClick={handleUpdateAudience}
                    endIcon={<ArrowDown2 size="16" color={theme.palette.text.primary} />}
                  >
                    <Typography color={theme.palette.text.primary}>
                      {Object.keys(AudienceEnum)[Object.values(AudienceEnum).indexOf(userPhoneNumber?.audience)]}
                    </Typography>
                  </Button>
                </Link>
                <LoadingButton loading={isLoading} type="submit" variant="contained" disabled={!isValid}>
                  Add
                </LoadingButton>
              </Stack>
            ) : (
              <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} alignItems="center" sx={{ px: 6 }}>
                <Button variant="text" color="error" onClick={() => handleDialogDeletePhoneNumber()}>
                  Delete
                </Button>
                <Link href={'/profile/select-audience-phone-number'} passHref>
                  <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    startIcon={<Eye size="18" color={theme.palette.text.primary} />}
                    onClick={handleUpdateAudience}
                    endIcon={<ArrowDown2 size="16" color={theme.palette.text.primary} />}
                  >
                    <Typography color={theme.palette.text.primary}>
                      {Object.keys(AudienceEnum)[Object.values(AudienceEnum).indexOf(userPhoneNumber?.audience)]}
                    </Typography>
                  </Button>
                </Link>
              </Stack>
            )}
          </Stack>
        </FormProvider>
      </Dialog>
```

Comment: add your form please

Answer (score 0):

```
useForm({
  mode: 'onBlur',
  reValidateMode: 'onChange'
})
```

> **mode**: onChange | onBlur | onSubmit | onTouched | all  <default: onSubmit>

This option allows you to configure the validation strategy before a user submits the form (onSubmit event).

> **reValidateMode**: onChange | onBlur | onSubmit  <default: onChange>

This option allows you to configure validation strategy when inputs with errors get re-validated after a user submits the form (onSubmit event). By default, validation is triggered during the input change event.

ref: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform

Comment: when I change my mode to 'onBlur', my 'add' button is disabled even I enter 10 numbers.

Comment: @AmirRezaie, you haven't passed the validation rules. refer the link.